# Excel- Referencing same cell from multiple sheets with text based names

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with multiple sheets,a summary sheet and then 12 other sheets, with sheet names, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr- all the way to Dec.

In my Summary sheet I am NOT adding up anything.  In my summary sheet, I have Column A2-A13 listing Jan-Dec.  In column B2-B13, I want to pull cell B7 from each sheet so that in column B2, I have Jan!$B$7, in column B3, I have Feb!$B$7, in column B4, I have Mar!$B$7 and so on.  I just don't want to have to go in and change Jan! to Feb! to Mar!.  Is there a way to tell excel to pull cell B7 from the next sheet if I am using sheets with text based names.  All over the internet, I find information that is useful if the sheets were named sheet 1, sheet 2, or month 1, month2 but there is NOTHING that seems to work if the sheets are named with text based names like Jan, Feb, Mar.  Can I accomplish this or is this just not a function that excel is capable of doing?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a column with the sheet names, you can use it.

In cell B2, put the following:

```
=INDIRECT(A2&"!B7")
```

The inner par will evaluate as `Jan!$B$7` and then `INDIRECT` converts the text into a reference.

You can now drag down this formula for the other sheets.